# Time line. Resource production changes at it's half, calculate total resources produced when player online?

Tags: php, algorithm, production, game-development

I am writing a game where player can build and upgrade buildings. They can have resource producing buildings. The game is updating resources amount at most recent as 10 mins. If users is inactive  for more than 10 min I calculate the correct amount the next time he updates the page.
The player can start upgrading a building at time 1. Their current gold production is 100. It's supposed to complete at time 100 and some of resource's production then increases to 600. But player logs in again at time 200. He is supposed to get 100+600 gold, but how to calculate it?

Perhaps update user_resources table with two columns - `previous_production` and `previous_production_active_till`.
When when calculating the resources check if last update is less than old production amount. If so, get prev_time_delta by doing `previous_production_active_till - last resources update`. Calculate how much was added in old rates until the previous_production_active_till, when calculate second sum for upgraded rate. For example, last update is at time 1. The old production is 100 per 100 time units. The old rate lasts till 100 time. The new rate starts at 100. Player logs in at time 200. Game does :

```
1-100=abs 99+1=100/100=1
100*1=100
```

now for remaining time we take new production rate,

```
200-100=100+1=101/100=1
600*1=600
```

A bit of background info, this is a PHP game, and the player interacts with the game with POST/GET requests. For optimisation consideration to reduce loads on Database I choose to update the player's resource by checkng on every page load for a specific time interval, 100 in this case since their last update and do every updates only then.

This is one option, any other way?

Answer (score 0):

> to reduce loads on Database I choose to update the player's resource
>   by checkng on every page load for a specific time interval, 100 in
>   this case since their last update and do every updates only then.

What if player will relogin every 2 minutes? Will his login request calc resources produced while he did previous login request?

I think you don't have to think only about `100 times` period of recalc player's harvest. By relogin player must receive also his harvest amount since previous login/calcHarvest request.

About buildings, I offer to consider two ways:

1. When building is upgrading it doesn't produce harvest. So you need to know `building_is_upgraded_timestamp`. And get `delta=(current_timestamp - building_is_upgraded_timestamp)`.  Then `EarnedHarvest = delta * Harvest_produce_per_second;`
2. When building is upgrading it produces harvest by `Harvest_produce_per_second` of old upgrade_level_building. Add `LastEarnedByThisBuildingTimestamp` to each mining building. So you need to know `building_is_upgraded_timestamp` and compare it with `current_timestamp`,

Look code:

```
//If we logged in firstly after building has been upgraded
if ( $current_timestamp > $building_is_upgraded_timestamp )
{
    $delta_old_level_building = $building_is_upgraded_timestamp - $LastEarnedByThisBuildingTimestamp;
    $delta_new_level_building = $current_timestamp - $building_is_upgraded_timestamp;

    $earned_harvest = $delta_old_level_building * $Harvest_produce_per_second_previous_level_building + $delta_new_level_building * $Harvest_produce_per_second_current_level_building;
}
else // Logged in and building is still upgrading
{
    $delta = $current_timestamp - $LastEarnedByThisBuildingTimestamp;
    $earned_harvest = $delta * $Harvest_produce_per_second_previous_level_building
}
```